# Why is there a repeated root to the Einstein energy-momentum relation?

Tags: electrons, dirac-equation

Using the metric signature $(+---)$, a particle in some reference frame $K$ moves with four-momentum $p^\nu$.  In this same frame we may define the  spacelike vector $U^\nu$ with the property $U^\nu U_\nu = -1$.  Now define a new four-vector
$$S^\nu \equiv p^\nu + mc U^\nu $$
As the components of this vector satisfy $U^\nu p_\nu=0$, then it follows that
$$S^\nu S_\nu = p^\nu p_\nu - m^2c^2 = 0 $$
and this is simply the Einstein energy-momentum relation.  Now suppose gamma matrices are introduced,
$$\gamma^\nu S_\nu \equiv \gamma^\nu p_\nu + mc \gamma^\nu U_\nu $$
The quantity $\gamma^\nu S_\nu$ is now a repeated root to the Einstein relation which can be proved by expanding,
$$[\gamma^\nu S_\nu]^2 = [\gamma^\nu p_\nu]^2 + mc \text{\{ $\gamma^\nu p_\nu$,  $\gamma^\nu U_\nu$ \}} + m^2c^2[\gamma^\nu U_\nu]^2 $$
The anti-commutator is zero while the last term satisfies $[\gamma^\nu U_\nu]^2 = -1$.  The result is four copies of the Einstein relation.

My question is the following: What is the meaning of the repeated root? Moreover, why is the repeated root not used in the field of physics?